# Putting fit equation on plot in one line

Tags: matlab, plot

I am using a curve fit and I would like to display the equation in the plot. I tried using a text but therewith the text is splitted and not in one line. That is probably due to the blanks before and after each variable. Is there a way to have the text displayed in one single line?
Here's my code:

```
pars=fit(time_s,p_bar,'exp2');
plot(pars);
a = num2str(pars.a);
b = num2str(pars.b);
c = num2str(pars.c);
d = num2str(pars.d);
hold on;
txt = {'p(t) = ' a '*exp(' b '*t) + ' c '*exp(' d '* t)'};
text(150,2,txt);
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your `txt` should be a string. Replace the `{` and `}` with `[` and `]` to do string concatenation.

Comment: txt = strcat(['p(t) = ', a, ' * exp(', b, ' * t) + ', c, ' * exp(', d, ' * t)']); this worked, thank you!

Comment: Using the square brackets is one way to do it, e.g. `['hello', ' ', 'world']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
txt = strcat(['p(t) = ', a, ' * exp(', b, ' * t) + ', c, ' * exp(', d, ' * t)']);
```

this works